# Notepad++ - how to add character to beginning of line

Tags: regex, sed, notepad++

I'm trying to add parenthesis to beginning and end of line in Notepad++. Using sed I would do:

```
   sed -i 's/^/(/' filename
   sed -i 's/$/)/' filename
```

and be done, but I have to use Notepad ++ on Windows. I went to find and replace, chose regular expressions and tried to replace "^" with "(", but I got "zero length match" and it doesn't add the character (same with replacing "$" with ")").

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer right after I posted the question. In case anyone is curious, in Notepad++ you have to escape the parenthesis characters whereas you don't have to in sed.

In Notepad++, under "Replace with", choose:

```
  \(
```

and it will work.

Comment: Your answer to your question is the solution. +1 :)

Comment: @Tensigh you don't need to have two regexes. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25133014/3297613

Answer (score 20):

In the search field put `^(.*)$` and in the replace field `\(\1\)`. This worked just fine for me.